# Ubuntu docker with multiple mysql container

Tags: mysql, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I hope you could help me.

I'm trying to setup a docker with multiple MySQL container in ubuntu server.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  mysql-db_1:
    image: mysql:8.0.28-debian
    command: --sql_mode="" --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - ./data_1/files:/var/lib/mysql-files
      - ./data_1/data:/var/lib/mysql

  mysql-db_2:
    image: mysql
    command: --sql_mode="" --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '3307:3307'
    volumes:
      - ./data_2/files:/var/lib/mysql-files
      - ./data_2/data:/var/lib/mysql
```

Everything is successfully built and I was able to connect to port 3306 however I can't connect to port 3307.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mysql-db_2` container port is invalid.

you can change it to `3307:3306`

so it will be exposed at port 3307, but the container itself will be listening on port 3306

```
  mysql-db_2:
    image: mysql
    command: --sql_mode="" --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '3307:3306'
    volumes:
      - ./data_2/files:/var/lib/mysql-files
      - ./data_2/data:/var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: I also tried that, but when I check the show variables like '%port%', it still shows port 3306 even though I'm connected using -P 3307. Or it is normal?

Comment: please paste in your docker ps so i can understand better.

Comment: Everything is good. I'm just a bit confuse because when I connect on both ports (3306,3307) and execute `show variables like '%port%'` shows 3306. But when I check the content both have different records, so everything working fine now.

Comment: That is understandable.
There are two 'players' here.
1. The docker container.
2. your computer.

Your computer is the host for the docker container. 
Every time you set up a docker container you need a port exposed **In the container** and from your computer.

For example : 

mysql-db_2 container will listen on port 3306 for HTTP request (or docker requests). and your computer will try to contact him using port 3306.

Using docker ps is a better usage for showing container run time ports, because it shows you the computer and container ports.